# Sencha Touch for mobile platforms

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have been hearing so much about Sencha Touch HTML/CSS/JQuery things.
I want to start with some samples. I have some basic questions:

1. which IDE to use ?
2. how portable the application is from one mobile platforms to other ?
3. Can we use the Device hardware like sensors in our application ?

Please guide me so that I can start my learning curve.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Doesn't really matter since Javascript isn't compiled: you will be debugging it in your browser, not your IDE. For what it's worth, I've been using Visual Studio, but something lightweight like Notepad++ should work just as well.
2. Anything with a web-kit browser can run it. So iOS, Android, Blackberry 6.0+. It does not work on Windows Phone for now.
3. To use device sensors, you need to have emulate native access; there is a framework called PhoneGap which wraps around your web app to do this. Sencha Touch has built-in PhoneGap integration support.